# Trying to align text in a div, HTML& CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align some text in my `div` which is acting as a nav bar.
I am trying to align the tags below to the very right hand side of my `div`.

This is my HTML and CSS code containing the information of my `div`, `ul` and `li` tags. I have already tried `text-align: right;` but to no avail. If you need anything feel free to ask.

```css
#navBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75;
  background-color: silver;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block
}
p {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
ul {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  font-family: 'Carter One', sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: .6em;
}
```

```html
<div id="navBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the nav bar i have created. I am trying to put the    links on the right hand side of the nav bar, is there any way i could do this? 
 Sorry if I don't use the correct terms but I am fairly new to web development and just need some guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6g2vbhu8/1/)**

```
ul {         
     float:right;
 }
```

Comment: Also you can simple remove `width: 600px` from `ul` element [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xe3w6tc1/)

Comment: yes.. its simple and you can use like as Alex suggested :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 ul {
  float: right;
 }
```

And don't forget a clearfix

```
ul::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Demo : http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/oXgeaX

Comment: and also how would i insert say a search box, like im not asking for code for the search box itself but how would I align that to the right or the div?

Comment: If you want it to the right of the menu you can just add another <li> to this <ul> with your searchbox inside it. It depends of what you need exactly